# NetCDF4 Python dimensions reordered

Tags: python, dimensions, netcdf

I am creating a NC file using netCDF4 in python. The file is quite simple and includes variables of 1 and 2 dimensions (1st dim=N, 2nd dim=M). But the problem is that when I read out the file, the dimensions of the 2D variables are interchanged, i.e. instead of coming out as data of dimension (N, M), they come out as dimension (M, N), while all 1D data comes out as (N, ), as expected.

The code looks something like this

```
root = nc.Dataset(filename, 'w', format='NETCDF4')
dimensions = ('N', 'M')

root.createDimension(dimensions[0], None)
root.createDimension(dimensions[1], None)

for field in fields:
        field_def = ...<defintion of field, how many dimensions etc...>
        if field_def[0] == 1: # how many dimensions in this variable
            chunk_size = (200, )
        else:
            chunk_size = (200, 1)

        dim = tuple(dimensions[:field_def[0]])
        var = root.createVariable(field, field_def[3], dimensions=dim,
                                fill_value=0,   chunksizes=chunk_size)
```

But when I read the file the dimensions of the 2D variables are opposite, i.e. the chunk size is (1, chunk_size) and dimensions are (M, N) not (N, M).

Anyone who as experienced something like this, or can see if I am doing something wrong? I have implemented the same in Matlab, but there it all comes out correctly.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you explicitly define the dimension sizes, e.g. `root.createDimension(dimensions[0], 200)`, `root.createDimension(dimensions[1], 1)`?

Comment: Why not just reverse their order in your code?  I.e. `dimensions = ('M', 'N')` or switching the order of the `createDimension` calls. The netCDF4-python package's native ordering is the reverse of many others, e.g. for (lon, lat, z, time) data it orders the axes (time, z, lat, lon).

Comment: Talking to the netCDF library maintainers, they don't know of anything that would causes that behavior. I'd start by opening an issue in netcdf4-python here: https://github.com/unidata/netcdf4-python/issues

Comment: It seems that there is a MATLAB "feature" and not a problem with the python library. Looking at the documentation for matlab netcdf.defVar: This function corresponds to the "nc_def_var" function in the netCDF
     library C API, but because MATLAB uses FORTRAN-style ordering, the
     the fastest-varying dimension comes first and the slowest comes
     last. Any unlimited dimension is therefore last in the list of
     dimension IDs. This ordering is the reverse of that found in the C
     API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this is not a python netCDF issue but more a "feature" of MATLAB netCDF. From the netcdf.defVar MATLAB documentation

This function corresponds to the "nc_def_var" function in the netCDF
library C API, but because MATLAB uses FORTRAN-style ordering, the
the fastest-varying dimension comes first and the slowest comes
last. Any unlimited dimension is therefore last in the list of
dimension IDs. This ordering is the reverse of that found in the C
API.

Thus, files generated using MATLAB are not compatible with other languages, unless you have some idea about dimension ordering, and can reorder variables when reading writing. But you have to be aware of this if files are to be used in software using another library/dimension ordering.